# How to add a total row for a Django Inline Model Admin?

Tags: python, django-models, django-templates

I'd like to add a row to Django Admin inline model where I can total calculated after-tax amounts.

I have two models: Appointments and Invoice_Line, and in the admin I am displaying Invoice_Line model as inline to Appointments (models admin registration shown below):

admin.py:

```py
class Inv_LineInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Invoice_Line
    extra = 1
    fields = ['item_desc','item_quantity','tip_amount','item_price','total_before_tax','stax_rate','stax_amount','total_after_tax']
    readonly_fields = ['item_price','total_before_tax','stax_rate','stax_amount','total_after_tax']


@admin.register (Appointment)
class Appointment(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('appointment_ref','create_date','appointment_date',
                    'appointment_time','assigned_associate',
                    'check_in', 'appointment_status', 'last_name', 'first_name')
    list_editable = ('assigned_associate','check_in')
    search_fields = ('appointment_ref','create_date','appointment_date', 'appointment_time','requested_associate__associate','assigned_associate__associate','check_in', 'last_name', 'first_name')
    list_filter = ('check_in','appointment_status',)
    inlines = [Inv_LineInline]
```

Admin change template looks as shown in the link below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvtoD.png)

I’d like to modify the inline to include a totals row where I can add up “Total After Tax” for all lines.  How would I go about doing that?

I am new to Django and would greatly appreciate any help I can get.